# Problem with rendering video in Kdenlive with title

Tags: video-editor, kdenlive

Recently I wanted to render a short video clip in Kdenlive which had title in beginning and end. The title was a simple text made by Kdenlive.
So, whenever I render the video with title, render stops in 0 to 4 seconds.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and the latest version of Kdenlive.

Comment: Write your solution found as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have done to bypass this problem.

I removed the title (which I made in Kdenlive) and made the title as a png file in Gimp.

This is not the solution. But I could render and get my file. (see it here: [Diwali; Festival of...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KiRDcqGzeCc))